# How can I fix a unity resolution problem?

Tags: unity-game-engine

can any help me?, When I compiled a game with resolution 1080 x 1920 the compiled was too diferent like the game view, How can I fix it?
[[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE4JQ.jpg)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGSZq.png)

[[my game settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eopkB.jpg)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr47e.jpg)

The resolution should be the same in the editor and the compiled version.

Comment: check your "Project setting -> Quality " maybe you enable the lowest resolution by default ?